# Open a local file with applescript within application

Tags: macos, applescript

How would I go about opening a file from within an applescript application? I'd place it in `/Contents/Resources` of my applescript application. What I want to know is what I would tell the actual script to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the path to your application, use the `path to me` command and build a path to your resource. Then, you can use Finder to open the file with the default program, or you can tell a specific program to open the file.

```
set filepath to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:file.ext"

tell application "Finder"
    open alias filepath
end tell

--OR

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open alias filepath
end tell
```